# Verb agreement with "that" as relative pronoun

Tags: relative-pronouns

Which one of the following sentences is grammatically correct?

> 1. The idea that introduces a new relational representation is the subject of this paper.
> 2. The idea that introduce a new relational representation is the subject of this paper.

Notice the form of the verb *to introduce* in the sentences.

Comment: _That_ is not a pronoun here; it's a complementizer and doesn't vary, hence it doesn't govern verb agreement in the relative clause. Instead, the antecedent NP (_the idea_) governs agreement, whether the clause is introduced with _which, who_, or _that_. (2) is incorrect, (1) is correct. And (3) _The ideas that introduce a new relational representation ..._ is **also** correct, because _ideas_ governs plural agreement on _introduce_.

Comment: You might rephrase it as: *An idea that introduces...* Unless you wish to claim that no other ideas introducing new relational representations are relevant. You might also skip the relative clause altogether, and trim the syntax as well: *This paper presents an idea for a new relational representation.*

Comment: @jlovegren Please see my comment @ terdon below.

Comment: @Kris see @ terdon 's comment to you :-)

Comment: @jlovegren :) same here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any way you look at those sentences, they are cumbersome and hard to read. Why don't you just say (note the use of *an* instead of *the*)

> The subject of this chapter is an idea that introduces a new relational representation.

In any case, of your two suggestions, the most correct would be the 1st:

> The idea that introduces a new relational representation is the subject of this paper.

In this case, the subject of the verb *to introduce* is *the idea*, since that is in singular form, you should use the 3d person singular (introduces) with it. Your second example makes no sense as written.

Comment: Is the word `that` in my sentences (and the sentence you suggested in your answer) a `relative pronoun`?

Comment: @Rasoul whatever John Lawler [said](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118661/verb-agreement-with-that-as-relative-pronoun/118664#comment242735_118661).

Comment: -1 Try not to suggest rephrasing when not specifically asked for. The question does not relate to 'writing effectively' (writersSE), rather the construction of the sentence and the use of a specific word.

Comment: @Kris you can't be serious! Why in the world not? The sentence suggested by the OP was very clumsy, why shouldn't I suggest an alternative? Editing suggestions may be off topic here and should not be requested, but I see nothing wrong with offering help.

Comment: @Rasoul you could make the argument that *that* is a relative pronoun, but Dr. Lawler's analysis is most standard.

Comment: re: "but I see nothing wrong with offering help." Sure, we have comments for that.

Comment: @kris I answered the question, I did not just suggest rephrasing. I simply chose to also point out that the sentence was clumsy. Unless you can point me to a section of the FAQ or a meta post that shows that the community is against offering advice, I suggest you stop making up imaginary rules. The comments are for asking for more information or clarification from the OP, the _answer_ is where you post advice and suggestions for improvement. In any case, down votes mean the answer is not helpful, not that the answer was _too_ helpful for your liking.